# How to compare with .index cell by cell in python

Tags: python

```
Y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,]
X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] 
Di = []
for number in Y:                        # as for each number in Y
    if number > 0:                      # and the number if more than 0
        if number in X:                 # compare to the numbers in X 
            if number not in Di:        # when in cases of number found not in X
                Di.append(number)       # Add to the Di
print("Di",Di)                          #print the letters Di and the value of the number 1 found
if Di == [1]:             # Condition   #if the value is equal to 1 print excluded
   print("excluded")      # Clause      #print excluded

else:
    print("not excluded")
```

Output

```
Di --> excludeed #because of digit 5 counting 0
```

The above code is from a python program that try to compare the 1 or 0 where it works as follow find the first value that is 0 in Y list and compare it with the value in the same position in the list X and if found positive exclude if not found negative go to the next 0 in the list Y and so on when the list is finished and could not exclude any print not excluded. hope this make sense but it is not doing its Function. if someone can modify it for me with .index to make the expected function this would make my life much happier.
kind regards
Basem

Comment: Please share the output you look for, that'd help

Answer (score 0):

```
Y = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
X = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

def excluder(yVal, xVal):
    for count, ele in enumerate(yVal):
        print("Current Y list value in this loop cycle:" + str(ele))
        if yVal[count] > xVal[count]:
            print(str(yVal[count]), " is greater in the Y list")
        elif yVal[count] < xVal[count]:
            print(str(xVal[count]), " is greater in the X list")
        else:
            print(str(xVal[count]), " X and Y are equal")

excluder(Y, X)
```

Output below....I included an enumerate function because it is a good way to get the count in a loop without having to increment a variable.

```
Current Y list value in this loop cycle:1
1  is greater in the Y list
Current Y list value in this loop cycle:1
1  is greater in the Y list
Current Y list value in this loop cycle:0
1  is greater in the X list
Current Y list value in this loop cycle:1
1  is greater in the Y list
Current Y list value in this loop cycle:0
0  X and Y are equal
```

Comment: when I have tried this it printed "1  is greater in the X list" even though the list is as follow Y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,]
X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] so it should not have excluded anything because the value 6 in the Y set is 1. In other words the value 5 in the list has changed the code has not.  thank you for your help and assistance.

Comment: Great job mate I have just added or = and I think it gives me the expected results if yVal[count] >= xVal[count]:

Comment: I edited the code and the logic now should be easier to follow. It is preferred to use enumerate in python when incrementing and I included an example of this as well.